# sort numerical array inside associative array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array in following this format:

```
Array 
( 
    [214] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => 500 [1] => 350
    )     
    [215] => Array
    ( 
        [0] => 500 [1] => 350
    )
```

I need to sort the array in ascending order, this is what I need:

```
Array 
( 
    [214] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => 350 [1] => 500
    ) 
    [215] => Array
    ( 
        [0] => 350 [1] => 500
    )
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
foreach($array_tarifa_dia as $row => $values)
{
    foreach($values as $row1 => $values1)
    {
        $array[$row1] = $values; 
    } 
}          
 array_multisort($array, SORT_ASC, $array_tarifa_dia); 


function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) 
    {
         return 0; 
     } 
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1; 
} 
uasort($array_tarifas1, 'cmp');


function cmp($a, $b) 
{ 
   if ($a[214] == $b[214]) 
   { 
       return 0; 
   } 
   return ($a[214] < $b[214]) ? -1 : 1; 
} 
uasort($array_tarifas1, 'cmp');
```

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sort%20array%20php)

Comment: uasort array multisort foreach

Comment: foreach($array_tarifa_dia as $row => $values){
  foreach($values as $row1 => $values1){
   $array[$row1]  = $values; 
 }
 
}

array_multisort($array, SORT_ASC, $array_tarifa_dia);

Comment: function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}


uasort($array_tarifas1, 'cmp');

Comment: function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[214] == $b[214]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[214] < $b[214]) ? -1 : 1;
}


uasort($array_tarifas1, 'cmp');

Comment: You will get an better response if you include all of your attempts in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**sort()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) on each array within the array.

```
foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
        sort($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/y30amrdS)